# Get number of hours (in decimal) that is spent in two timeframes

Tags: formula

I have a booking system inside my Salesforce that has a start DateTime and an End DateTime. I am wanting to find out the number of hours spent in 2 different time frames. 07:00:00 to 21:00:00 & 21:00:00 to 07:00:00

We charge for the rooms on 2 Tarriffs for electricity. 
Off_Peak_Rate__c 
On_Peak_Rate__c

The timeframes are: 
Off Peak - 21:00:00 to 07:00:00 (Monday to Friday; & 24/7 on Saturday & Sunday)

On Peak - 07:00:00 to 21:00:00 (Monday to Friday)

I want to find the number of hours for each time frame in a On_Peak_Hours__c and a Off_Peak_Hours__c formulas.

Here's the code I have so far for On_Peak_Hours__c, but it doesn't really work if the Start__c time starts in an off-peak time.
I also have a formula Field (Day_of_the_week__c) that says what day the booking is made on. (My local time is GMT+10; so the code below the "11" is actually 9pm, and the 21 is 7am; there is no Daylight Savings Time)

```
if(AND(HOUR( timevalue(Start__c))  >= 11 , HOUR( timevalue(Start__c)) <= 21.00, 
        OR(Day_of_the_week__c = 'Monday', Day_of_the_week__c = 'Tuesday', Day_of_the_week__c = 'Wednesday', Day_of_the_week__c = 'Thursday', Day_of_the_week__c = 'Friday')
            ),
            0,
                FLOOR( 
                    MOD( 
                        (End__c - Start__c  ) * 24, 24 
                        ) 
                     ) 
    )
```

This outputs the correct number of WHOLE hours if the booking is made solely in on peak timeframe, but I need it to show that if it's reserved for 9.5 hours, it would do the 0.5 as well.

Ideally, if someone made a booking (on a weekday) for 07:15:00 to 22:00:00, it would equal 13.75 On peak, and 1.0 Off peak.